# Output multiple chacters to the same location in the Windows command console without overwriting

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to output multiple characters to the same location in a console window, without overwriting/clearing any of them

Simply moving the cursor position to the x and y coordinates seem to clear the existing character and write the new one to the screen.

```
cout << "O";
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
cout << "I";
```

I was hoping that would create an O/I hybrid, with the 2 occupying the same screen space, instead of just an I.

Comment: That's not how the console works. Each cell contains one character.

Comment: The duplicate is not a duplicate.  The duplicate proposes positioning things at a specific location without the use of the ANSI control characters.  This question talks about superimposing glyphs to produce a hybrid.  Totally different in my opinion.  (The answer, btw should just be a simple "No".  That's not possible.) But the proposed duplicate is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Wyck. I was afraid it would get marked duplicate since I searched quite a bit and found questions worded similarly, but meaning something else. As for it not being possible, now I know!